# How to sign in VS Code Azure Function extension with a service principal (clientid and secret)

Tags: azure, function, visual-studio-code, azure-service-principal

How to sign in to the VS Code Azure Function extension with a service principal (client ID and secret)?

[image]

I don't have contribute access to my account and would like to use my service principal to contribute.

Comment: Could you confirm whether that **Service principal** has **Contributor access** or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't sign in VS Code Azure Function extension with a service principal.

***You must use the CLI command below to Sign in with the Service Principal.***

```
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant>
```

```
az account set --subscription "subscription_name"
```

**Output :**

[image]

*This will not set your Azure account with service principal id and when you use DefaultAzureCredentials or try to deploy function app it will deploy it with this account.*

Try deploying your function with this command in your CLI:-

```
func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>
```

**Reference :**

Check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli-service-principal) to Sign in with the Service Principal.